# In bash, what's the best way to exit with the status of a previous command after cleaning up

Tags: bash

I have a very simple script that does something like the following

```
#!/bin/bash$
/some/path/buildAll.sh \
&& filepath=/tmp/`cat /some/path/conf/version`.tar.gz \
&& (cd /some/path && tar czf $filepath .) \
&& push_file_to_web $filepath
```

I want to clean up the tarball with `rm $filepath` regardless of whether the above succeeded and exit with the status of the whole command. In other words, the script should exit with status 0 exactly when every step including the cleanup succeeded. What's the cleanest way to do this?

Comment: As an aside, you need to add a fair bit of quoting to make this safe. As it is, if the `version` file contains glob characters or whitespace, you could have a bad day. http://shellcheck.net/ might be your friend, in identifying the specific cases.

Comment: As a second aside, you might consider `bash -e` (or `set -e` within your script), to get the behavior of exiting on first failure without needing the `&&`s. That said, do mind the caveats: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the best practice is to use an EXIT trap:

```
#!/bin/bash

cleanup() { rm -f "$filepath" || exit $?; }
trap cleanup EXIT

foo && bar && baz
```

If you don't want to define a function, this could me more tersely written:

```
trap 'rm -f "$filepath" || exit $?' EXIT
```

The trap will not modify your exit status unless `rm` fails.

---

(As an aside: While `exit $?` is *usually* exactly equivalent to the default behavior of `exit` if called with no arguments, this is not true within an EXIT trap; in this scenario the argument is in fact necessary to override the pre-trap exit status. Thanks to [@5gon12eder](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1392132/5gon12eder) for assistance in my discovery of this behavior).

Comment: What about `cleanup || exit 1`?

Comment: @5gon12eder, where? Inside the EXIT trap? Has no effect there. Outside the trap? Unnecessary, because default behavior at the end of the script is to return the exit status of the last command, so forcing that exit status to `1` rather than faithfully passing through the exit status of `rm` is simply throwing away information.

Comment: @5gon12eder, ...incidentally, passing through `$?` as the current exit status is also the default behavior for shell functions (so `return $?` is always unnecessary). If you want to do something or exit if it fails, `foo || exit` is just as good as `foo || exit $?`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I've meant to use `finally() { cleanup || exit 1; }; trap finally EXIT; something;`.  It will exit with 0 status if and only if both `something` and `cleanup` succeeded.  If `something` fails but `cleanup` succeeds, it will exit with the status of `something`.  If `cleanup` fails, it will always exit with status 1.  Had I omitted the `exit 1`, it would have exited with status 0 if `something` succeeded but `cleanup` failed.  As you (maybe?) say, `exit $?` or `exit` might have been the better alternative if `cleanup` can fail with a status other than 1.

Comment: @5gon12eder, unfortunately, that behavior isn't reliable; I've definitely observed there to exist bash releases which will ignore the status provided by an `exit` command within an EXIT trap.

Comment: ...hmm. I say that, but then have some issues trying to reproduce it. Unfortunately, the coworking space I'm at right now is closing, so I'll need to investigate further at a different time.

Comment: @5gon12eder, ...okay. Tracked it down, and it turns out the behavior I remembered was due to the behavior of `exit` behaving differently inside a trap with no arguments passed. `exit $?` or `exit 1` both behave properly (for this use case) in that situation, whereas an `exit` invocation with no arguments doesn't modify the exit status which would have been used had the trap not existed. It was thus my habit of using `foo || exit` culminating in that result. :)

Comment: Isn't `$?` the exit code of `rm` instead of `baz`? Shouldn't you use `cleanup() { ec=$? ; rm -f "$filepath" || exit $?; exit $ec; }`?

Comment: You probably also want `set -o pipefail`

Comment: @AaronDigulla, no, I don't need pipefail -- there are no pipelines here, and `foo && bar && baz` already uses the return value of the first item in the chain to fail. And if the trap _doesn't_ call `exit` explicitly (and with an argument), then the default behavior already is using the preexisting exit status.

Comment: @AaronDigulla, ...which is to say, answering your question more explicitly: `$?` is indeed the exit code of `rm` within the function, and that's in accordance with desired behavior.